# AS3 How to make an object shrink when it is not tapped

Tags: actionscript-3

I have stumbled upon a problem that I do not seem to know how to solve. I have searched it up online but no answer has been found. It is that when you tap the Monster on the screen it grows, but when you don't tap it returns to its default size. I have managed to make it grow when tapped but I can not seem to make it so that when you release the tap it shrinks. An example of what I am talking about is on cookie clicker, that when you click the big cookie it grows but when you don't it goes to its original size. Here is my code so far:

```
var score:Number = 0;
var score_str:String;
var score_str_len:int;

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

Monster.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler);

Monster.width = 363.5;
Monster.height = 344.9;

function fl_TapHandler(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    Monster.width = 378.4;
    Monster.height = 359;

    score = score + 1;

    score_str = score.toString();
    score_str_len = score_str.length;

    Taps_txt.text = 
        score_str_len > 3 

        ? score_str.substr(0, score_str_len-3) + ',' + score_str.substr(score_str_len-3) 
        : score_str
    ;

}
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [actionscript reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html), there are a lot of other touch events you can use, such as TouchEvent.TOUCH_OUT or TouchEvent.TOUCH_END.

I haven't used them so i can't tell you which one would be helpful to you but you can run some tests and see which of the event is fired when you remove your finger from the monster, just as you would do with mouse events.

So basically you would add another listener (best would be inside the fl_TapHandler function) for the release touchevent and put the monster variables back to their normal level.

If you want to have several monsters, the best way would be to create a class for it and call the functions that would be inside this class. Exemple:

```
Monster.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, Monster.fl_TapHandler);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about you store all monsters in an array?

```
var monsters:Vector.<Monster> = new Vector.<Monster>();
monsters.push(new Monster());
monsters.push(new Monster());
monsters.push(new Monster());

for(var monster : monsters) {
    if(monster.isTapped){
        monster.grow()
    } else {
        monster.shrink()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry,  but as I am only just starting as3 I don't understand. Please may you simplify it.

Comment: @user3406023 In that case it's best you learn some OOP (Object Oriented Programming).

Comment: I fail to see how that answer helps the OP. You've provided nothing to help him achieve what he asks help for.

Comment: @FabriceBacquart I provide a higher level idea for how to structure things.